# Including NSIS script in CMake

Tags: cmake, windows-installer, installation, nsis, cpack

Is it possible to include an NSIS script from CMake that uses CPack together with NSIS? It appears that I'm limited to only a few commands ([doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CPackNSIS.html)), but some commands suggest that there is a way to include the whole NSIS script, particulary:

```
CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_PREINSTALL_COMMANDS,
CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_INSTALL_COMMANDS,
CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_UNINSTALL_COMMANDS
```

However, when I try to call these commands:

```
SET(CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_PREINSTALL_COMMANDS "!include extra_preinstall.nsh")
```

Nothing happens. (Excluding `/NONFATAL` throws an error, so presumably the script cannot be found.)

Checking basic functionality:

```
SET(CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_PREINSTALL_COMMANDS "MessageBox MB_OK \\\"Hello world!\\\"")
```

Doesn't do anything with the installer.

Why doesn't a Hello World button appear? Why is the script file not found (even though I put it on every level of CMake hiearchy)?

Comment: Years ago I just modified the NSIS script that comes with CMake to add the features I needed.

Comment: I looked into that, which affirmed my feeling, that there MUST be a way to include an external NSIS script.

Comment: I name my replacement NSIS script as `NSIS.template.in` and  put it in my local modules folder that is added via the command `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake/External/Modules)`

Comment: @drescherjm I've resolved this slightly differently. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preinstall doesn't mean that it's executed before the install section, so you actually have to click "install", then the command is executed.
The same goes for Install and Uninstall.

As for including external scripts: including with absolute path solves everything. If absolute path is not available, it can be easily obtained using CMake tools.